# I have an issue with mips floating point registers

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

I am using the following code to get numbers in the floating point registers:

```
mtc1.d $t3, $f3
mtc1.d $t1, $f1
```

but then I get strange values in them such as 1.67E-312, am I doing something wrong, do I have to convert the values before I use them?

Answer (score 2):

> do I have to convert the values before I use them?

Yes. The `mtc1` instruction merely copies the bits from the GPR to the FP register without any conversion. To convert to a double you would use `cvt.d.w`:

```
mtc1.d $t3, $f3
cvt.d.w $f3, $f3
```